# Properties of generalized characters

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters

I search for generalized characters which are not characters.Also I want to know that why every generalized character is a difference of characters.

Comment: This is more-or-less a tautology. A "non-negative" integral linear combination of characters is a character (you just verify that there is an appropriate direct sum that affords this as its character). Now, a generalised characters allows any integral linear combination, so you sift out the positive and the negative ones and there you have your two characters whose difference is the given generalised character.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean a generalized character $\chi$ is a linear combination $\chi = \sum_{i = 1}^n d_i \chi_i$ of characters $\chi_i$ with coefficients $d_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, it follows that a generalized character is a character if and only if $d_i \geq 0$ for all $i$. Assume that $\chi$ is not a character, so that $d_i < 0$ for some $i$. Reindexing the $\chi_i$, we may suppose that there is an $m \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $d_i \geq 0$ for $i \leq m$ and $d_i \leq 0$ for $i > m$. Set
$$
    \alpha = \sum_{i=1}^m d_i\chi_i
$$
and
$$
    \beta = -\sum_{i=m+1}^n d_i\chi_i.
$$
Then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are generalized characters with all positive coefficients, and so $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are actually characters. Also, it follows immediately from their definitions that
$$
    \chi = \alpha - \beta.
$$

Comment: @Kim, I think Dan's answer should be tagged as the right one. If you keep refraining from doing so and do not acknowledge all the other people that take the time to answer your questions, then you take a risk of being removed from this community.